# Automatically enter while loop

Tags: loops, while-loop

I am having trouble with the while loop in my code. The instructions say to "Set a loop-control variable to a value that automatically enters the loop for the first time". Any suggestions on how I can do this? Any input will be appreciated. Thank you!

}//end main

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: You could use a `do{....}while(condition)`.. Or does it have to be a `while(condition){...}`?

Comment: I have to use both actually.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you don't know what most of these terms mean.

A while loop assumes the following syntax (I'll do it in C# since I'm not sure what language you're coding in; update your original post and I'll change my samples):

```
while (/* loop control/condition here */)
{
    // Code here
}
```

This evaluates like this in english (pseudocode):

```
while the loop control is true
    do this
when it equals false leave the while
```

So what you want to do is initialize a variable (I'm using type `bool` here for clarity's sake) and put it in between the parenthesis as the "loop control."

Here's a small sample:

```
bool daytime = true; // This is the loop control.
int i = 0;

while (daytime == true) // We are seeing if it's day out.
{
     System.out.println("It is daytime.");
     if (i == 6) {daytime = false;} // If our counter hits 6:00 it's nighttime.
     i = i + 1; // Increment our counter.
}
```

Anyway hope that helps you.  Good luck!

### Edit: Do-While

I may have misunderstood your original question a bit, this is what a do-while loop looks like:

Syntax:

```
do
{
    // Code here
} while (/* loop control/condition here */);
```

Pseudocode:

```
do this code
keep repeating code until the condition is false
```

Sample:

```
bool daytime = true; // This is the loop control.
int i = 0;

do
{
     System.out.println("It is daytime.");
     if (i == 6) {daytime = false;} // If our counter hits 6:00 it's nighttime.
     i = i + 1; // Increment our counter.
} while (daytime == true) // We are seeing if it's day out.
```

Comment: How can I translate this to Java language? Sorry I forgot to specify that. Thanks for the answer by the way!

Comment: @Beg.Programmer1 Done!  The two languages are so similar I only had to change the Console.WriteLine :)

Comment: Thank you! :) I just don't understand how to make it go into the while loop automatically. What control variable can I use?

Comment: @Beg.Programmer1 Anything that would initially be true the first time the while loop shows up.  Unless I'm misunderstanding you.  If you're talking about going into the loop whether the condition is true or not, then you're looking at a do-while loop.  I can update the answer if that's what you want!

Comment: @Beg.Programmer1 I added a do-while for you.  If this is what you were looking for please remember to accept my answer!  Good luck!